# Using modals in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am creating a web app using codeigniter and Twitters CSS framework Bootstrap.

I am wondering how I go about implementing their modal system [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) with the 'views'. I want to be able to click a button in a view file and for it to link to a controller but the view to open in the modal. If that makes sense? Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing fancy. Just follow their examples and use `<?php echo anchor('controller/method'); ?>` inside the modal buttons instead of the actual buttons.

Comment: that works but it doesnt show the modal on top of the current view. it just shows it on its own.

Comment: Review the javascript and jQuery requirements for using modals.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this on my current project, and I use jQuery's `$.ajax` to load the url into a modal element and then fade that into view.

In the controller, if I want modal markup to load, I use this:

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    $this->load->view('some/view_modal', $data);
}
else 
{
    $this->load->view('some/view', $data);
}
```

If your markup is simple enough, you can extract just the container element you need when you do the AJAX call, but for me I found it simpler to use two views.

In your case, you can simply pass the AJAX response data to the Bootstrap modal function.